# Mysql if date is between existing dates in table

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to get a listing of everything between two dates, including those items with start and end dates before and after a specific date.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE (userid = '#' AND exstartdate >= '2015-07-25' 
AND exenddate <= '2015-08-24') OR (userid = '#' AND reg='Yes') 
ORDER BY eamount DESC LIMIT 0, 25

eid ename           eamount userid  exstartdate exenddate   paid    reg
1   Bill 1          1000        #   2015-01-01  2015-11-01  no      Yes
17  bill 17         300         #   2015-07-29  2015-07-29  no      No
2   Bill 2          85          #   2013-11-01  2017-12-31  no      Yes
6   Lunches         80          #   2015-01-01  2016-12-31  no      Yes
```

I'm trying to get this in as well:

```
3   Bill 3         87.00    1   Yes 2015-01-01  2016-05-01  no  No
```

but can't seem to do it unless I reverse the > and <. Bills 1, 2 and lunch are showing up because of the reg flag.

I'm wondering if this would be better to do with PHP instead.

Edit: To clarify, I'm looking to get all items that are between $date1 (Seen above as 2015-07-25) and $date2 (2015-05-24) from the table. The table has start dates and end dates that if the date from the table includes the date listed in $date1 and $date2.

So if $date1(2015-07-25) is after exstartdate(2015-01-01) and $date2(2015-08-24) is before exenddate(2015-11-01) then it shows the result.

Also show if exstartdate and exenddate is between $date1 and $date2.

Basically, if the dates between exstartdate and exenddate also match a date  between $date1 and $date2, then show result.

Comment: I think you should re-phrase your question. It sounds like you want to find all active items for that range, i.e. the end date is _not after_ X and the start date is _on or before_ Y. Providing an [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and your expected results would help clarifying.

Comment: You should consider the "between" clause

Comment: Thank you to all who answered.   Firebladedan: I tried with betweens as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description you want:

```
SELECT * FROM expenses 
WHERE userid = '#' AND 
    ((exstartdate >= '2015-07-25' AND exenddate <= '2015-08-24') OR 
     (exstartdate < '2015-07-25' AND exenddate > '2015-08-24') OR 
     reg='Yes') 
ORDER BY eamount DESC LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't think to do the double bracket. *Head desk*

Answer (score 0):

There's a HUGE pile of overlap cases for two date ranges. complete overlap, no overlap at all, partial overlap with all kinds of before/after variations. e.g. your fields in the db are `a` and `b`, and the date range you're testing are `x` and `y`:

```
    a    b
x y              - simple, no overlap at all
           x y   - simple, no overlap at all
x   y            - x outside, y inside/on
x     y          - x outside, y inside/on
x        y       - x outside, y inside/on
x           y    - complete overlap
    x       y    - y outside, x inside/on
      x     y    - y outside, x inside/on
         x  y    - y outside, x inside/on
   xy            - x = y = a
         xy      - x = y = b
      xy         - complete overlap
```

It gets ugly, so... which of these cases do you need?

Comment: It would the complete overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to find all rows where the interval of `exstartdate` to `extenddate` overlaps with the two dates you're providing. The row that you're missing is failing to match because one interval is inside the other. You will need something like this:

```
WHERE
exstartdate BETWEEN a AND b
OR
exenddate BETWEEN a AND b
OR
(exstartdate <= a AND exenddate >= b)
```

Where `a` and `b` are your interval start and end dates. You should keep in mind such queries can be very slow with even a thousand records.